# Writing payload to a file in mule using SFTP

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want to write my payload to file using SFTP. Reason why I want to do this is I have large number of records and is difficult to process those records and it would be easier to download the large file and process the data.How can I achieve that ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use SFTP connector where you want to write payload.You can use append feature of connector if you want to write multiple payload in same file.

Comment: Thanks anupam, could you please help me with an example. I am pretty new to mule. I don't want to append the payload. I have a payload which I need to write to a file and transport using SFTP. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: just add sftp connector after processing your data. use default settings so it will not append.